# Help: cannot find vertex_normal as attribute in 2.93 beta

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am following this tutorial on geometry nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQVYieRfQBY&t=12s which is using 2.93 Apha. I couldn't find the alpha so I downloaded the beta. My issue is that at 3:38 they select vertex_normal and I cannot find this attribute in 2.93 beta. Please help.
[image: Tutorial screenshot]

This is what I am getting [image]

Comment: Actually selecting "normal" makes the animation do the same thing as in the tutorial.

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative setup is suggested in the first (pinned) comment of the video.

TLDR : You can use `normal` instead of `point_normal` although it may be inaccurate. If you want an accurate result you can read through the rest of the answer.

Quotes from user Erindale :

> A note on vertex_normal attribute: This has been removed as it as a
> bit of a misnomer (although very useful). The method you'll need to
> use now is to take normal attribute (this is the face normals) with an
> Attribute Convert node (set to point (writes to point domain) and
> vector (normal is a vector)) and then use an Attribute Vector Math
> node set to Normalise to ensure those vectors all have length 1. I
> recommend people make a reusable node group that handles this as it is
> a pretty common thing to want. Here is an example of what that could
> look like

From the twitter post :

https://twitter.com/erindale_xyz/status/1374764284811612161/

[image]

> As a follow up, you can just use `normal` as an attribute instead of
> vertex_normal and it will automatically convert to point domain if
> it's used with another point domain attribute (eg position). There
> will however been some inaccuracies without normalising. For effects
> like this you may well get away with it unnoticed but with more uneven
> geometry you may find that normalising is required. I just have a
> group so that's what I recommend